# Proving $\gcd(P,Q) = 1 \implies \gcd(P+Q,PQ)=1$

Tags: polynomials

> How can I prove that if $\gcd(P,Q) = 1$, with $P$ and $Q$ are
>   polynomials, then $\gcd(P+Q, PQ)=1$

I used Bezout lemme but I couldn't find the appropriate combinaison.

Answer (score 2):

$$\gcd(P,Q)=1\Longrightarrow\gcd(P+Q,Q)=1\land\gcd(P,Q+P)=1\Longrightarrow\gcd(P+Q,PQ)=1$$
This holds in any GCD domain.

The first implication should be obvious and for the second use the $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,c)=1\Longrightarrow\gcd(a,bc)=1$ [rule](http://planetmath.org/propertiesofagcddomain).

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to use Bezout, by it  $\ \gcd(p,q)= 1\,\Rightarrow\,ap+bq = \color{#c00}{\bf 1}\,$ for some $\,a,b\,$ thus

$\ \color{#c00}{\bf 1} = (ap+bq)^2 = (a^2p+b^2q)( \color{#0a0}{p+q}) -\color{#0aa}{pq}(a-b)^2$

Therefore we deduce that $\ d\mid \color{#0a0}{p+q},\,\ d\mid\color{#0a0}{pq}\,\Rightarrow\, d\mid \color{#c00}{\bf 1},\,$ hence $\,\gcd(p+q,pq) = 1.$